# How best to implement a taxonomy of sectors, groups, and stocks in Python

Tags: python, list, taxonomy

I am working on a project that involves a stock market taxonomy: market, sector, group, stock. At present there is one market, 15 sectors, 100 groups, and 1,500 stocks. The data is currently stored in a text file like this.

```
market1
*sector1
**group1
***stock1
***stock2
***stock3
**group2
*sector2
*sector3
```

My current thought is to parse a flat file to a list of lists, but I suspect that there must be a better, more Pythonic, way. Perhaps JSON, XML... How would you do this if you were starting from scratch?

Comment: Are you asking how the data should be stored or how the example file should be parsed?

Comment: How the best to store the data for use in Python. The example file was just to make the data structure clear.

Comment: Ok, yes use JSON

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON

```
 {"some_market":{"some_sector":{"some_group", [{"name":"stock_one"}]}}}
```